# Set a checkbox initial state to checked if some condition is met on the server side

Tags: php, html, checkbox

How to can I check a checkbox by default if some condition is met?

```
if ($php = "yes"){
    // check.box is check
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Title and content now precisely reflect the author intent. Fixed typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
            $checked = ""; 
            if ($php == "yes"){   
                 $checked = "checked"; 
            } 
 ?>
<input type="checkbox" <?php echo $checked;?>/>
```

Comment: it works but it's still checks even if $php !=  yes.

Comment: Did you try with `==` instead `=`? Inside condition

Comment: @fdsfds  for a very shorter code you can check my answer.No need of extra variable creation at-all.Only one line code is enought

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" <?=($php == "yes")? 'checked' : '';?>/>
```